# Solving the Python video output lagging & crash. I'm using webcam to count the number of Person/Car/Truck that passed an area

Tags: python, opencv, count, webcam

I want to make a Person/Car/Truck count program using Python and Pycharm using webcam.

The video source is from a webcam (private link).

When the 'Person' button (on the left side) is clicked, from that moment, everytime a person walk accross the red line (green line is the starting parameter), the program will count it as 1 person and continue counting until the same
Person' button (on the left side) is clicked. Same goes for 'Car' button and 'Truck' button. The total count for Car and Truck is also shown at the window.

I already have a working code for to do this but whenever I run the program (py file), for unknown reason, when I clicked the 'Person/Car/Truck/Bus button, the video will crash/stop or sometime later after that. Also, the video output is lagging from actual second from the private webcam.

A) How do I add buffer to the video output because the video output is lagging behind?

B) How to solve the video output crash?

**Crash error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Fadhli/License Plate Recognition/Mark1/mark5.py", line 109, in <module>
    img_frame_90 = rescale_frame(frame, 90)
  File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Fadhli/License Plate Recognition/Mark1/mark5.py", line 30, in rescale_frame
    width = int(image.shape[1] * percentage / 100)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
[rtsp @ 0000011437d43840] RTP: PT=60: bad cseq 4512 expected=36e9
[hevc @ 0000011437e2ea40] Could not find ref with POC 42

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Full coding:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Resolution Pixel Size
# 640 x 480 - Standard Definition(SD)
# 1280 x 720 - High Definition(HD)
# 1920 x 1080 - Ultra High Definiion(HD+)
# 3840 x 2160 - Ultra High Definition(UHD or 2K)

cyanColor = (255, 255, 0)
pinkColor = (255, 0, 255)
yellowColor = (0, 255, 255)
greenColor = (0, 255, 0)
blueColor = (255, 0, 0)
redColor = (0,0,255)

path_vid = "Resources/video/license_plate.mp4"
path_main_ent = 'rtsp://~~~/Streaming/Channels/101'
path_parking_Lot = 'rtsp://~~~/Streaming/Channels/101'

button_person = False
button_car = False
button_truck = False

counter = 0
nmsThreshold = 0.3
confThreshold = 0.4

def rescale_frame(image, percentage):
    width = int(image.shape[1] * percentage / 100)
    height = int(image.shape[0] * percentage / 100)
    new_frame = (width, height)
    return cv2.resize(image, new_frame, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

def click_button(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global button_person
    global button_car
    global button_truck

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(x,y)

        #   ------  Person Button Clicking  ---------
        polygon_person = np.array([[(20, 160), (200, 160), (200, 230), (20, 230)]])
        is_inside_person_button = cv2.pointPolygonTest(polygon_person,(x,y),False)
        if is_inside_person_button>0:
            print("YAYYYY, We're clicking inside Button!!",x,y)

            if button_person is False:
                button_person = True
            else:
                button_person = False

            print("Now Person Button is: ",button_person)

        #   ------  Car Button Clicking  ---------
        polygon_car = np.array([[(20, 250), (200, 250), (200, 320), (20, 320)]])
        is_inside_car_button = cv2.pointPolygonTest(polygon_car, (x, y), False)
        if is_inside_car_button > 0:
            print("YAYYYY, We're clicking inside Button!!", x, y)

            if button_car is False:
                button_car = True
            else:
                button_car = False

            print("Now Car Button is: ", button_car)

        #   ------  Truck Button Clicking  ---------
        polygon_truck = np.array([[(20, 340), (200, 340), (200, 410), (20, 410)]])
        is_inside_truck_button = cv2.pointPolygonTest(polygon_truck, (x, y), False)
        if is_inside_truck_button > 0:
            print("YAYYYY, We're clicking inside Button!!", x, y)

            if button_truck is False:
                button_truck = True
            else:
                button_truck = False

            print("Now Truck Button is: ", button_truck)

# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov3.weights", "dnn_model/yolov3.cfg")
# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov3-spp.weights", "dnn_model/yolov3-spp.cfg")
# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov3-tiny.weights", "dnn_model/yolov3-tiny.cfg")
# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov4.weights", "dnn_model/yolov4.cfg")
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov4-tiny.weights", "dnn_model/yolov4-tiny.cfg")

model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
model.setInputParams(size=(640,480), scale=1/255)

classes = []
with open("dnn_model/classes.txt","r") as file_object:
    for class_name in file_object.readlines():
        class_name = class_name.strip()
        classes.append(class_name)

# print("- Object List -")
# print(classes[0])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_main_ent)
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_parking_Lot)

cv2.namedWindow("Frame")    # The name should be same with cv2.imshow("_Name_")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Frame",click_button)

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    # print(type(frame))
    img_frame_90 = rescale_frame(frame, 90)

    line_frame_above = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (190, 430), (1220, 470), yellowColor, 2)
    line_frame = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (180, 440), (1220, 480), blueColor, 4)
    line_frame_bottom = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (170, 450), (1220, 490), yellowColor, 2)

    polygon_person = np.array([[(20, 160), (200, 160), (200, 230), (20, 230)]])
    cv2.fillPoly(img_frame_90, polygon_person, greenColor)
    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, "Person", (50, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, blueColor, 2)

    polygon_car = np.array([[(20, 250), (200, 250), (200, 320), (20, 320)]])
    cv2.fillPoly(img_frame_90, polygon_car, greenColor)
    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, "Car", (50, 290), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, blueColor, 2)

    polygon_truck = np.array([[(20, 340), (200, 340), (200, 410), (20, 410)]])
    cv2.fillPoly(img_frame_90, polygon_truck, greenColor)
    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, "Truck", (50, 380), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, blueColor, 2)

    polygon_truck = np.array([[(20, 430), (200, 430), (200, 500), (20, 500)]])
    cv2.fillPoly(img_frame_90, polygon_truck, greenColor)
    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, "Bus", (50, 470), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, blueColor, 2)

    (class_ids, scores, bboxes) = model.detect(img_frame_90,nmsThreshold=nmsThreshold, confThreshold=confThreshold)

    if len(class_ids) != 0:
        for class_id, score, bbox in zip(class_ids,scores,bboxes):
            (x,y,w,h) = bbox
            class_name = classes[class_id]
            xmid = int((x + (x + w)) / 2)
            ymid = int((y + (y + h)) / 2)

            if class_name == "person" and button_person is True:
                cv2.rectangle(img_frame_90, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), pinkColor, 2)
                cv2.circle(img_frame_90, (xmid, ymid), 3, redColor, -1)
                # cv2.putText(img_frame_90,str(class_name),(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,yellowColor,2)
                if ymid > 431 and ymid < 500 and xmid > 170 and xmid <1220:
                    line_frame = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (350, 440), (1220, 480), greenColor, 4)
                    counter += 1

            if class_name == "car" and button_car is True:
                cv2.rectangle(img_frame_90, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), greenColor, 2)
                cv2.circle(img_frame_90, (xmid, ymid), 3, redColor, -1)
                # cv2.putText(img_frame_90,str(class_name),(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,yellowColor,2)
                if ymid > 431 and ymid < 507:
                    line_frame = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (350, 440), (1220, 480), greenColor, 4)
                    counter += 1

            if class_name == "truck" and button_truck is True:
                cv2.rectangle(img_frame_90, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), cyanColor, 2)
                cv2.circle(img_frame_90, (xmid, ymid), 3, redColor, -1)
                # cv2.putText(img_frame_90,str(class_name),(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,yellowColor,2)
                if ymid > 431 and ymid < 507:
                    line_frame = cv2.line(img_frame_90, (350, 440), (1220, 480), greenColor, 4)
                    counter += 1

    cv2.putText(img_frame_90, 'Total Vehicles : {}'.format(counter), (0, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, yellowColor,2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame",img_frame_90)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Forget question A and B. First check if you are able to read the frames in `ret,frame = cap.read()`. What does `ret` return? Does `frame` contain an image?

Comment: I couldn't dnn_model/classes.txt.